# Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers such that $a − 7b + 8c = 4$ and $8a + 4b − c = 7$. What is the value of $a^2 − b^2 + c^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across this peculiar problem which is intriguing me for quite some time.

I tried to find out the value of $a$ and $c$ in terms of $b$ and then replacing the values in the expressions which is to be found — in a hope that the $b$'s would cancel out however no avail.

I even tried adding up and multiplying both the equations to see if they result in a meaningful equation – one which I can correlate with the expression which we have to find.

Please note: the answer has to be a constant, not a function of the variables.

Comment: So? The answer should be a constant, not a function of $c$ or for that matter $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I agree now with value 1.

Answer (score 5):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a+8c=4+7b, \\
8a-c=7-4b;
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
(a+8c)^2=(4+7b)^2, \\
(8a-c)^2=(7-4b)^2;
\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a^2+16ac+64c^2=16+56b+49b^2, \\
64a^2-16ac+c^2=49-56b+16b^2; \\
\end{array}\right.$$
so the sum of both last equations is

$$
65a^2+65c^2=65+65b^2,
$$

hence
$$
a^2+c^2-b^2=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

From $c=8a+4b-7$, 
$$a-7b+8(8a+4b-7)=4\implies b=\frac{12-13a}{5}$$
to have
$$c=\frac{-12a+13}{5}$$
So,
$$a^2+(c-b)(c+b)=a^2+\frac{a+1}{5}\cdot\frac{25(-a+1)}{5}=a^2-a^2+1=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The linear system is not determined because there are three unknowns with only two equations therefore infinitely many values for $(a,b,c)$. However we can find all expression $E(a,b,c)$ in $a,b,c$ puting two variables, say $a$ and $b$, in function of the parameter $c$ so we get a function $E(c)$.

For the given expression $E(a,b,c)=a^2-b^2+c^2$ it is find the constant $1$ but also, for example, with the expression
$25c^2+25b^2+a^2-50bc+10ab-10ac$ $\space$   we get the constant $1$.

Many examples of expression can lead to functions not necessarily constant.